# WebPart toolpart changes PeoplePicker output

Tags: 2013, page-layout, people-picker, edit-form, toolpart

I have a strange behavior when using a peoplepicker field in a page layout. 
When I open the toolpart for a webpart, the field's content is rendered diffrent:

**Normal**

[image: standard people picker]

[image: field value]

**With toolpart**

[image: standard people picker]

[image: field value]

### **The markup**

Userfield:

```
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldUserField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--MS:<PageFieldUserField:UserField FieldName="aea1a4dd-0f19-417d-8721-95a1d28762ab" runat="server">-->
    <div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Kontakt</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"></div></div>
<!--ME:</PageFieldUserField:UserField>-->
```

Simpe fieldvalue output:

```
<div id="SocialBoxContact">
    <!-- MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="aea1a4dd-0f19-417d-8721-95a1d28762ab" runat="server" /> -->
</div>
```

I have no idea why the fields output is diffrent when a toolpart is opened - can someone point me in an direction ?